# What happens to main thread when using a callable

Tags: java, multithreading

When using Callable and Future in Java, what happens to the main thread when the other thread is executing the Callable. Is it sleeping and the other thread wakes it up when it has finished computing the value

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
public class AddData {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future<Integer> result = service.submit(() -> 30+11);
        System.out.println(result.get());
    } finally {
        if(service != null) service.shutdown();
    }
  }
}
```

With multithreading is it possible to see the current status(sleep, doing something) of thread like using VisualVM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example the thread is going to block on the completion of the future. So on Linux it is removed from the run-queue of the scheduler and placed on a wait-queue where it will remain until future completes; then it will be reinserted into the scheduler and will get its chance to run. It will run very soon because it will be inserted at the beginning of the run-queue (look for Completely Fair Scheduler for more information).

Comment: Note that this doesn't happen _because the other thread is executing the callable_, it's happening _because the main thread decided to wait on it_.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by pveentjer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65535994/642706) is correct.

## Project Loom

The dynamics of a situation such as your example will be more clear when [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) arrives. Preliminary [builds are available](http://jdk.java.net/loom/) now based on early-access Java 16, as the Java team invites feedback.

### `ExecutorService` is `AutoClosable`

In Project Loom, the `ExecutorService` interface becomes `AutoClosable`. This means it can be used with [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax.

After the code block of the try-with-resources, flow-of-control blocks to wait automatically until all submitted tasks are done.

No need to explicitly shutdown the executor service. The executor service gets shutdown automatically when its `close` method is called after the `try` block, as part of being `AutoCloseable`.

Rather than block on `Future#get`, you can collect your `Future` objects as they are instantiated. Then later check them after the `try` block.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class AddData
{
    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        Future < Integer > additionFuture = null;
        try (
                ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
        )
        {
            additionFuture = service.submit( ( ) -> 30 + 11 );
            // … submit any further tasks for threaded work.
        }
        // At this point, flow-of-control in this thread (the main thread) blocks until all submitted tasks are done.
        // When flow-of-control here resumes, the `ExecutorService` will have been automatically shutdown via its `close` method called as an `AutoCloseable`.

        // Handle any `Future` objects you tracked.
        if ( additionFuture.isCancelled() ) { … }
        else {  // Else not cancelled.
            System.out.println( additionFuture.get() );
        }
    }
}
```